# worklight change android push-notification icon

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'v searched the android website, worklight, google and stackoverflow and couldnt get any 'How-To' about changing the push-notification icon ('push,png').
I did find and was able to change the App icon ('icon.png') but no luck finding a solution/example on how to and where do it for the notification....
any help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "solution/example". You just need to replace the image file.

The push.png file resides in `your-project\apps\your-app\android\native\res\drawable-*` (where * refers to one of the HDPI, LDPI, MDPI, XHDPI folders, you'll need to replace all of them or just the ones you'd like, per the device support requirements of your application).

Try then to simply replace that push.png with whatever you'd like there instead of the default image provided by Worklight. Don't forget to re-build the application so that the change will be applied to the generated Android project.